# Hollywood movie with a girl who stays with her family after her murder

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw one Hollywood movie in 2012, in this movie one family has two girl and one boy. They go to school every day. One elder girl gets a camera as a gift or buys it on her birthday (I don't remember perfectly). She takes photos and she completes more than 12 camera rolls; her father promises her one clean roll every month. So in her next birthday she'll have all her photos with her.

But her neighbor make one groove for trapping her and when she returns from school, he asks her to visit it and she goes with him. There he rapes and kills her. On the other side, her family start looking for her and they also complain to the police but it is worthless. That girl lives around with her family, after death.

The graphics and scenes in this movie are very pretty. That girl's soul tries to inform her father that her neighbour killed her. At last that neighbour dies due to sharp ice dropping on his head. I think this movie was also nominated for an Oscar.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're looking for Peter Jackson's [The Lovely Bones](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0380510/combined) from 2009.

> A 14-year-old girl in suburban 1970's Pennsylvania is murdered by her neighbor. She tells the story from the place between Heaven and Earth, showing the lives of the people around her and how they have changed all while attempting to get someone to find her lost body.

The bit with the camera is in it as well (the girl wants to be a photographer) and also the ending with the deadly  icicle. Stanley Tucci was nominated for a Best Supporting Role Oscar as the murderer. The movie was based on a [novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lovely_Bones) from 2002. Here's the trailer:

Comment: This movie affected me so deeply. I woke up the night after watching it crying. I think its brilliant.

Comment: Haven’t seen the movie, but the book its based on (also *The Lovely Bones*) is fantastic.